# Mixing and iterating list of tuples into a text template

Tags: python, arrays, django, python-3.x

I got a list and a list of tuples, each containing strings:

```
names = ['joseph', 'parker', 'john']
interests = [('apples', 'design'),('bananas','economy'),('pears','medicine')]

text_template = 'hi my name is {name}, i like {interests}, im studying {interests} everytime / '
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
hi my name is joseph, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is joseph, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is joseph, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime 


hi my name is parker, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is parker, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is parker, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime 

hi my name is john, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is john, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is john, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime
```

thanks, all!!

Comment: You use `{% for .. %}` loops.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a slight change to your template, such that field names are not duplicated.

```
text_template = 'hi my name is {name}, i like {interest}, im studying {degree} everytime / '
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for name, (interest, degree) in product(names, interests):
...:    print(text_template.format(name=name, interest=interest, degree=degree))
...:    
hi my name is joseph, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is joseph, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is joseph, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime / 
hi my name is parker, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is parker, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is parker, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime / 
hi my name is john, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is john, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is john, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime /
```

... and in case the blank lines are important:

```
>>> for i, (name, (interest, degree)) in enumerate(product(names, interests), 1):
...:    print(text_template.format(name=name, interest=interest, degree=degree))
...:    if not i%len(names):
...:        print()
...:        
hi my name is joseph, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is joseph, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is joseph, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime / 

hi my name is parker, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is parker, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is parker, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime / 

hi my name is john, i like apples, im studying design everytime / 
hi my name is john, i like bananas, im studying economy everytime / 
hi my name is john, i like pears, im studying medicine everytime /
```

Comment: Thanks!!, you helped me a lot, I'm starting to learn about for loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['joseph', 'parker', 'john']
interests = [('apples', 'design'),('bananas','economy'),('pears','medicine')]
for i in names:
    for j in interests:
        text_template = 'hi my name is '+i + ', i like '+ j[0]+', im studying '+j[1]+' everytime / '
        print (text_template)
```

This should work.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept and upvote the answer. Thanks.